# Excel Management for Inventory

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, inventory

Okay, hope this question will be clear enough that I can get an answer. Thanks for the help.

The situation is that I am downloading some information into two different spreadsheets which contains orders from two different stores.

The problem is that between these two stores the model numbers (SKU#) for a lot of items are different even though the product is the same. There is no changing that now. I do have a list of equivalencies. For example, I know that 00-XX-55 is the same in Store 1 as 22-FF-33. There isn't a logical equivalency so I would be setting them manually.

My question is if there is any way I can combine data from two sheets and set up manual equivalencies while doing this? Would excel allow me to manage the data in that way I can join the two unequal SKUs

Answer (score 0):

You need a two-column translation table.  Once you have this you can manage combined inventory because you can then determine the total inventory of a single item in both stores.

Answer (score 0):

So in a solution do you want to translate all to the store 1 sku, the store 2 sku, or a third warehouse sku? I guess what I am driving at here is that there needs to be a superior synonym to sort of design around.

To build a translation table you would put the original sku (the sku that you will convert from, sort of the inferior number you do not want to go by for purposes of the summarization) into column A and the master sku into column B. We will call this sheet "converter".

You could either have:

```
A, B
00-XX-55, 22-FF-33
```

This could normalize everything to the 22- sku. Or you could do this:

```
A, B
00-XX-55, 123abc
22-FF-33, 123abc
```

This way if you want to normalize to a third value rather than either of the stores values.

In your inventory page col C is the sku column so in column D put =iferror(vlookup(C, converter!A:B, 2, false), C) and populate that all the way down. Now in each row you have the original and the master sku next to each other in C and D. If the sku was not found in the converter table then it would just use whatever value was in C. You can then build pivots tables using D to group them on.

Comment: Well, the case is actually that a lot of SKU's from store 1 have a certain logical order to them. But the items in store 2 are random (they were not generated by my system but by another). So I would like to translate them into the SKU's of the first store. <br/> A iferror(vlookup) function would do this for me? I am sorry if I am writing like this is a little over my head. <br/>